Error during `python setup.py develop` and `pip install -r requirements.txt`
I'm encountering an issue while trying to install the dependencies for my Python project using setup.py and pip install -r requirements.txt in Windows Poweshell.
Here's my setup.py:
import setuptools

with open("README.md","r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
    
setuptools.setup(
    name = "titanic-prediction",
    version = "0.0.1",
    author = "author",
    author_email = "author@gmail.com",
    description = "simple repo for exercise",
    long_description = "long_description",
    long_description_content_type = "text/markdown",
    url = "",
    packages = setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers = ["Programming Language :: Python :: 3"],
    install_requires = [
        "matplotlib",
        "numpy",
        "pandas == 1.1.4",
        "scikit-learn == 0.22", #(>= 3.5)
        "seaborn == 0.11.0"],
    python_requires = ">=3.7"
)

and this is my requirements.txt
install_requires =[
"matplotlib",
"numpy",
"pandas==1.1.4",
"pydantic==1.6.1",
"scikit-learn",
"seaborn==0.11.0",
],

Then I try to run python setup.py develop, but I got this error:
running develop
D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py:41: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  easy_install.initialize_options(self)
D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  self.initialize_options()
running egg_info
writing titanic_prediction.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to titanic_prediction.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to titanic_prediction.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to titanic_prediction.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'titanic_prediction.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'titanic_prediction.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating d:\data analyst\github\lokalhangatt\pacmann - git\minggu_4\4. advanced data manipulation\pertemuan 8 - data preprocessing pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\lib\site-packages\titanic-prediction.egg-link (link to .)
titanic-prediction 0.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed d:\data analyst\github\lokalhangatt\pacmann - git\minggu_4\4. advanced data manipulation\pertemuan 8 - data preprocessing pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\simple_pipeline
Processing dependencies for titanic-prediction==0.0.1
Searching for scikit-learn==0.22
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/2c/04e10167991ed6209fb251a212ca7c3148006f335f4aadf1808db2cbeda8/scikit-learn-0.22.tar.gz#sha256=314abf60c073c48a1e95feaae9f3ca47a2139bd77cebb5b877c23a45c9e03012
Best match: scikit-learn 0.22
Processing scikit-learn-0.22.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dxw9q95a\scikit-learn-0.22\setup.cfg
Running scikit-learn-0.22\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dxw9q95a\scikit-learn-0.22\egg-dist-tmp-a2evsbeb
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dxw9q95a\scikit-learn-0.22\setup.py:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
  from pkg_resources import parse_version
Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dxw9q95a\scikit-learn-0.22\setup.py", line 195, in check_package_status
    module = importlib.import_module(package)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 167, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 209, in setup_context
    yield
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 270, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 52, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dxw9q95a\scikit-learn-0.22\setup.py", line 303, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dxw9q95a\scikit-learn-0.22\setup.py", line 291, in setup_package
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dxw9q95a\scikit-learn-0.22\setup.py", line 219, in check_package_status
ImportError: numpy is not installed.
scikit-learn requires numpy >= 1.11.0.
Installation instructions are available on the scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\simple_pipeline\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    setuptools.setup(
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 117, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 183, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 199, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 954, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 35, in run
    self.install_for_development()
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 127, in install_for_development
    self.process_distribution(None, self.dist, not self.no_deps)
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 788, in process_distribution
    distros = WorkingSet([]).resolve(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 892, in resolve
    dist = self._resolve_dist(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 928, in _resolve_dist
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1266, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1302, in obtain
    return installer(requirement) if installer else None
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 710, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 737, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 934, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1206, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1192, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 260, in run_setup
    with setup_context(setup_dir):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(value)
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 201, in setup_context
    with save_modules():
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(value)
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 180, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in resume
    raise exc.with_traceback(self._tb)
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 167, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 209, in setup_context
    yield
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 270, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 52, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dxw9q95a\scikit-learn-0.22\setup.py", line 303, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dxw9q95a\scikit-learn-0.22\setup.py", line 291, in setup_package
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-dxw9q95a\scikit-learn-0.22\setup.py", line 219, in check_package_status
ImportError: numpy is not installed.
scikit-learn requires numpy >= 1.11.0.
Installation instructions are available on the scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

Then when I try to run requirements.txt, it shows an error like this:
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '–r': Expected package name at the start of dependency specifier
    –r
    ^

Is there any mistakes from my setup.py or requirements.txt files? And how to solve it?

You use a wrong character for -r option; Python options parser (and any othe options parsers) expects simple dash (ascii minus) but you use n-dash. Compare these:
-r (simple dash, minus)
–r (n-dash)
—r (m-dash)
Use simple dash, minus: pip install -r

requirements.txt just has the list of package names and versions.  It's not Python code.  Yours should simply look like this:
matplotlib
numpy
pandas==1.1.4
pydantic==1.6.1
scikit-learn
seaborn==0.11.0


Thank you for your advice, sir. I changed my requirements.txt to your suggestions but it still shows the same error as this. Can I run requirements.txt first before I do python setup.py develop?

Well, you don't "run" requirements.txt.  It just sits in your project folder and gets used by pip when you do a pip install.
